# Spring Cloud Implement RateLimit using redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to implement Request rate limit using Springboot cloud gateway and Redis.

My Spring version is **2.5.12**

spring-data-redis : 2.7.13

Here is my keyResolver

```
@Override
  public Mono<String> resolve(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress())
        .map(InetSocketAddress::getAddress)
        .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
        .map(Mono::just)
        .orElse(Mono.empty());
  }
```

ReactiveStringRedisTemplate as

```
@Bean
  public ReactiveStringRedisTemplate reactiveStringRedisTemplate(){
    return new ReactiveStringRedisTemplate(lettuceConnectionFactory);
  }
```

RedisRateLimiter as

```
@Bean
  public RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter() {
    return new RedisRateLimiter(10,10,60);//defaultReplenishRate,defaultBurstCapacity,
  }
```

Now I am trying to understand what is RedisRateLimiter and how it's work.

I want to achieve following things. I tried many things, but not able to understand how it calculate this requests.

1. 5 request / minute
2. 7 request / minute
3. 20 request / minute

Can someone please help me to understand this RedisRatelimiter with example in context of above 3 scenarios ?

Thanks,
Alpesh

Comment: Spring 2.5 was released in November 2007. I don't think it supported Java 8.

Comment: Yes it supports, because everything else is working with java8